# how to test css(3) style property value support, repeat value support?

Tags: javascript, testing, css

I am trying to detect if a css3 proprety support a given value. For example how can i test if -moz-transform supports rotateX(val) value. It is know that -moz-transform support matrix, skew, rotate but not 3d rotateX (that is supported by webkit browsers only for now). How can I test it? any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test 3d transformation support you need to test for 'perspective',

In pseudo code...

```
for prefix in prefixes
  element.style[prefix + "-perspective"] = 1;
  if element.style[prefix + "-perspective"] 
    return true
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that the prespective was associated with the support of css 3d

Comment: That's the way Modernizr does it